# Hardening a Chromebook

Tags: hardening

I have a Chromebook I routinely use for things like e-banking and other things where a security breach would be catastrophic.  I've read it is a very secure OS by nature due to its small surface area for attacks.  That said, are there any steps I should take to harden my Chromebook? Or is it as secure as it can be right out of the box?

Comment: Secure as far as there is no malware for Chrome OS until today if I am right. Encryption (PGP/GPG), safe browsing, antivirus + firewall, updating software and so one applies to any OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For things like e-banking Chrome devices are secure by default. You don't need to do anything special. There is a good overview about the security [here](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chromiumos-design-docs/security-overview), and a hardening guide [here](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chromiumos-design-docs/system-hardening). But you should be aware that your Google account is in fact a part of the system so you should protect the account by things like using a strong password and two factor authentication to maximize security.